# Which version of Kafka are impacted due to Log4j CVE-2021-44228?

Tags: security, apache-kafka, log4j

Which versions of Kafka are impacted by [CVE-2021-44228](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell)?

Nothing is yet updated on *[Apache Kafka Security Vulnerabilities](https://kafka.apache.org/cve-list)* about this vulnerability.

Comment: Probably better to create a JIRA about this

Answer (score 26):

### Update 2021-12-15

[APACHE KAFKA SECURITY VULNERABILITIES](https://kafka.apache.org/cve-list) has confirmed:

1. [CVE-2021-45046](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-45046)

> Users should NOT be impacted by this vulnerability

2. [CVE-2021-44228](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228)

> Users should NOT be impacted by this vulnerability

3. [CVE-2021-4104](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-4104)

> Version 1.x of Log4J can be configured to use JMS Appender, which publishes log events to a JMS Topic. Log4j 1.x is vulnerable if the deployed application is configured to use JMSAppender.

So please check the site for details.

### Update 2021-12-13

As suggested by bovine, log4j1.x may also be affected to this vulnerability.

> strictly speaking, applications using Log4j 1.x may be impacted if their configuration uses JNDI. However, the risk is much lower.

please refer to [this link](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/608#issuecomment-990494126) for latest status.

### Evidence for not using log4j2

By checking `dependencies.gradle` of Kafka:
[1.0.0](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0.0/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L59)  and [3.0.0](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.0.0/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L77)
both are using 1.2.17.
As the issue is affecting version [from 2.0-beta9 to 2.14.1](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html), Kafka is not affected by this security vulnerabilities.

Comment: The vulnerability additionally [impacts all versions of log4j 1.x](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/608#issuecomment-990494126); however, it is End of Life and has other security vulnerabilities that will not be fixed.  (Quote: "log4j 1.x contains a JMS Appender which can use JNDI. So I would say that, yes, log4j 1.x is also impacted by this vulnerability")

Comment: Instead of the "update"s, it would be better if the answer appeared ***as if it was written today*** (the revision history contains the historical information). E.g., if something is no longer the case, it should be deleted. The rest can probably be covered by qualification by version ranges.